# graph api token creations fails due to Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to login.window.net:443. Graph explorer also not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to implement user creation in Azure AD. Tried graph explorer with the below link. But it is not working, showing "We had an issue sending this request to the Graph API".
https://login.windows.net/oauth2/token?api-version=2.0

Also tried in localhost, then shows:

> Curl error: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to
>   login.window.net:443

Please help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

That link is to try and acquire a token.  That is unnecessary in Graph Explorer. Just click the "Sign-in with Microsoft" button, and enter your tenant admin credentials.  Then select POST for the operation and https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users.  In the request body put the properties that are required to created a new user, as described in https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_users.  NOTE:  When trying this operation, you may be required to consent for administrative permissions - make sure you select User.ReadWrite.All, and consent.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my requirement is to signup my site users with Azure AD. So we can use its authentication for the login. So I think the admin user should be already logged in or pass a authenticated token when a user try sign up.

Comment: Please look at our samples and documentation on OpenID Connect for signing users in. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-openid-connect-code